# ¿Que debo usar IaaS, PaaS o SaaS? #Azure

Tags: azure, servicio

Tengo este caso, se maneja robots automaticos los cuales se ejecutan como una aplicación de consola. Esta aplicación lanza un browser (Chrome Firefox IE), y que a través de Selenium va interactuando con la pagina. Que servicio de Azure me recomiendan usar. La información que se usa es sumamente sensible cabe resaltar.

Comment: Hola Tatiana, gusto de leerte por estos lares, aquí un ex-MSP de UPAO.net, bienvenida al sitio de SOes, podrías ser un poco más específica? Qué deseas lograr? Saludos.

Comment: Genial! tambien soy ex-MSP de la UNCP. Lo que se quiere es migrar unos robots son aplicaciones en consola pero tmb se requiere mantener el dominio por completo de ellos. Y cual es lo viable quiza me este equivocando bueno necesito conocer mas del asunto.

Answer (score 1):

Son cosas diferentes y no son intercambiables en la mayoria de los casos.

- IaaS: (Infraestructura como servicio) Contratas una maquina virtual. La configuras como quieres y eres el responsable de que funcione, de actualizarla, etc. Es la mas potente de las formas de cloud computing pues te da la libertad de hacer lo que quieras en la maquina.
- PaaS: (Plataforma como servicio) Contratas una software de base (por ejemplo un server web). Solo despliegas (deploy) la aplicación y otros se encargan del hardware y sistema operativo. Es una forma no tan potente pero mas practica para algunas soluciones.
- SaaS: (Software como servicio) Contratas un servicio CERRADO. (por ejemplo, JIRA). Solo usas el servicio, no puedes agregar componentes (generalmente).

En definitiva, no hay mucha chance de elegir, en general, salvo entre IaaS y PaaS ya que se trata de un servicio web, deberas sopesar costos + beneficios - limitaciones.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad Azure no tiene nada que ver con la ejecucion de test, podrias montar el sitio en un `Web Site` de azure y ejecutar manualmente los test abriendose el browser de forma local

El tema es como automatizas la ejecucion y para eso se podria usar

[Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx)

en este tiene funcionalidad de [Integración continua](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/continuous-integration-vs)

Con este podrias automatizar en la nube la ejecucion de los test, parece ser que `Selenium` esta soportado

[Get started with Selenium testing in a continuous integration pipeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium)

Comment: En este caso Selenium se usa como consola, no solo como test. Recomendación ¡Help!

Comment: pero si usas una tool de integracion continua podrias ejecutarlos sin necesidad de una consola, solo que Team Foundation debe integrar en la compilacion la ejecucion de los test. Esto al menos sera asi si quieres hacer un deploy automatico en Azure

Comment: Ajam, mas claro que el agua nos vamos Visual Studio Team Services