# Se puede ejecutar Selenium como consola, mas no como test en Azure?

Tags: azure, consola, selenium

Los robots se ejecutan como consola desde selenium, lo que se requiere saber es si Azure soporta SELENIUM no solo como test.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comente en la pregunta anterior 
[¿Que debo usar IaaS, PaaS o SaaS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13917/que-debo-usar-iaas-paas-o-saas-azure)

No es un tema de Azure, es un tema de la tool que uses para la integracion continua, en tu caso esta tool estara seguramente en Azure para realizar el deploy automatizado.

Si vas a usar Team Foundation o [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) integrado en Azure, estas tools son las que deben permitir ejecutar los test de Selenium, la consola no afecta en nada.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu lo puedes automatizar de forma local ejecutando comandos por CMD o por PowerShell entonces lo puedes ejecutar en Azure configurando la pipeline para que se ejecute en un agente propio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que tienes que hacer es Instalar un Agente en una maquina: sea un servidor, o en tu maquina de desarrollo. Lo importante es que la maquina tenga salida a Internet y que la maquina este encendida cuando ejecutes la pipeline.

Luego puedes ejecutar cualquier comando por cmd o powershell. Dichos comandos se ejecutan en la maquina donde esta corriendo el agente.

Instalar un agente es super simple:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahí copias y lo ejecutas en un powershell en la maquina donde quieres instalar tu nuevo agente.